# Unsolicited job offers even though no job search preference was set

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, email

SE should never assume that, just because the option has not yet been set, people are happy to receive emails about job requests.  I, for certain, was less than impressed that I received an email regarding 'A job that was perfect for me' ... it really wasn't!

If you have to take a default option, then surely it would be wiser to err on the side of caution rather than spam someone.

The primary difference between my situation and the suggested duplicate, is that I had not set any options in the job search status section, as I don't use it.

Comment: You have a point... but on the grand scale of things (compared to the ██ing █████ers at LinkedIn, for example) this still seems fairly benign. I doubt it will happen again.

Comment: Oooo!  Harsh language there, Mr Pekka! ;o)  It certainly won't happen again ... until next time!

Comment: It's not - I didn't actually have any job specifics set-up, so the argument in that post is not quite the same.

Comment: You mean that perfect job wasn't a good fit for a rockstar developer like you? It offers excellent perks in a unique environment with the opportunity to make a big impact!

Comment: I thought those mails require that you set the "I'm interested in jobs" checkbox at some point, either the "not actively looking" or the "actively looking" version. But if you haven't checked anything, you shouldn't get any mail. Or did I understand that wrong.

Comment: You're absolutely on the nail @MadScientist - I don't actually use the job section, and none of the radios were selected.

Comment: I think this is a different issue than the duplicate. Also most of the other complaints about job mails I remember were people that had their preference set to "not actively looking, but interested". This is about someone that didn't indicate a preference in either way.

Comment: Ahh, fair, I see. Voting to reopen then

Comment: @Pekka웃: Of course - the question is valid and not the same as the other.

Comment: I've added a different related post to the mix: [Job recommendations box in activity page spams users](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351196)

Comment: There's a bug lurking in here; I've switched off the emails and am doing a spot of code spelunking now. Details soon.

Comment: I also got spammed; however, no changes to my developer story that I am aware of (I don't use it; unless I did something by accident). but what bothered me even more than the fact that I got unsolicited mail was just *how* badly off the jobs were. Two or three of them were for language tags I had set to ignore... why would I be sent jobs for language tags I don't even want to see questions on?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, this is embarrassing... I'll start with the targeting criteria for these emails:

- Must be one of the following:

  - Marked as actively looking for a job
  - Engaged on jobs in the past 14 days (and haven't set state to 'not looking')
- And have the following attributes:

  - some indication of *where* you want to work
  - not been active on jobs in the past hour or so

We then use your match preferences (falling back to information from your [Providence profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/prediction-data)) to determine which jobs match you.

In your case you were targeted because we saw that you were engaged in jobs in the past 14 days. Except I checked and you weren't. So what happened? Because of a bug we were inadvertently implying engagement whenever you saved changes to your developer story. That causes a sync process to run that was unconditionally setting that active date.

I'm fixing that now, invalidating all the existing data and re-backfilling them from traffic logs right now.

Apologies for this inconvenience, I'm still assessing the damage but hopefully that'll be it. Thanks for the heads up <3

Comment: No probs.  I'm just a hater of spam, I'm afraid.  Still **LOVE** SE, though.